# How to calculate the frequency of each value in a column corresponding to each value in another column in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset as follows:

```
 col1   col2
    A   1
    A   2
    A   2
    B   1
    B   1
    C   1
    C   1
    C   2
```

I want the output as:

```
 col1  col2  Frequency
    A     1      1
    A     2      2
    B     1      2
    C     1      2
    C     2      1
```

I tried using the aggregate function and also the table function but I am unable to get desired result.

Comment: Wouldn't it be desirable to create some sort of community wiki post for this question, since it arises so often?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a dummy column or use the `rownames` to aggregate on:

```
aggregate(rownames(mydf) ~ ., mydf, length)
#   col1 col2 rownames(mydf)
# 1    A    1              1
# 2    B    1              2
# 3    C    1              2
# 4    A    2              2
# 5    C    2              1
```

`table` also works fine but will report combinations that may not be in your data as "0":

```
data.frame(table(mydf))
#   col1 col2 Freq
# 1    A    1    1
# 2    B    1    2
# 3    C    1    2
# 4    A    2    2
# 5    B    2    0
# 6    C    2    1
```

---

Another nice approach is to use "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, .N, by = names(mydf)]
```

Comment: deleted my answer which also uses data.table given you have it all ensembled in one post :), I would use setDT instead of as.data.table and name the column appropietly: `setDT(df)[ , .("Frequency" = .N), by = .(col1, col2)]`

Comment: @grrgrrbla, Thanks for the comment, but  (1) I prefer to not modify the other person's data using `setDT` unless *I know* that *they know* what that does, and (2) renaming columns is a pretty standard task and in my opinion is not critical to the question asked here.

Comment: (It's a matter of personal preference, I know.)

Comment: good points, I am used to servicing people perfectly, but you are right a little work on their part should be doable... and your points on setDT are also understandable, given it could lead to bugs if people don't understand what it does,

Comment: lol I am not sure whether this site should be about "servicing people perfectly" (says another new user)

Comment: me2, I am really annoyed with all the duplicate-questions even though I have been visiting the site regularly and contributing only for 2 months, it makes me want to just post links everywhere

Answer (score 2):

if your data is

```
col1 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C")
col2 <- c(1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2)
df <- data.frame(col1,col2)
```

you can use `dplyr`

1) `group_by` both both variables, since your output is supposed to include every combination of them

2) count the number of observations for each group using `n()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(col1,col2) %>% summarize(frequency=n())


# output
  col1 col2 frequency
1    A    1         1
2    A    2         2
3    B    1         2
4    C    1         2
5    C    2         1
```

Comment: This could be shortened to: `df %>% count(col1, col2)`